# Как в Google Sheets API писать в разные диапазоны?

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet

Пытаюсь разобраться в Google Sheets API на PHP 7. В общем, как правильно заполнить range, чтобы получилось так?

```
|______|Name|____|____|
|  Date|Qwer|Wert|Erty|
|1.2.20|1234|2345|3456|
```

Третья строка заполняется отдельно, другой функцией.
Возвращаясь к вопросу.
Я попробовал сделать так:

```php
$range = 'B1:B1,A2:E2';
$values = [["Name"],["Date", "Qwer", "Wert", "Erty"]];
```

Ясен пень ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unable to parse range: B1:B1,A2:E2",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Unable to parse range: B1:B1,A2:E2",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Я смотрел документацию, но так и не понял смысла в этом, как это использовать?

```
{
  "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
  "data": [
    {
      "range": "Sheet1!A1:A4",
      "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
      "values": [
        ["Item", "Wheel", "Door", "Engine"]
      ]
    },
    {
      "range": "Sheet1!B1:D2",
      "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [
        ["Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
        ["$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Задайте начальную точку в range (например, `Sheet1!A1`), а потом пишите влево и вниз, как вам надо

```
curl --request PUT \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/ABC123/values/Sheet1!A1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"values":[["","Name"],["Date","Qwer","Wert","Erty"],["1.2.20","1234","2345","3456"]]}' \
  --compressed
```

Endpoint

```
v4/spreadsheets/ABC123/values/Sheet1!A1
```

Required params

```
valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
```

Data

```
{
  "values": [
    ["", "Name"],
    ["Date", "Qwer", "Wert", "Erty"],
    ["1.2.20", "1234", "2345", "3456"]
  ]
}
```

### BatchUpdate

Задавайте диапазоны в размер данным. Если вы не укажете имя листа, то будет считаься, что редактируется первый лист.

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/ABC123/values:batchUpdate?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"valueInputOption":"USER_ENTERED","data":[{"range":"Sheet1!B1","values":[["Name"]]},{"range":"Sheet1!A2:D3","values":[["Date","Qwer","Wert","Erty"],["1.2.20","1234","2345","3456"]]}]}' \
  --compressed
```

Endpoint

```
v4/spreadsheets/ABC123/values:batchUpdate
```

Required params

```
Нет
```

Data

```
{
  "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
  "data": [{
    "range": "Sheet1!B1",
    "values": [
      ["Name"]
    ]
  }, {
    "range": "Sheet1!A2:D3",
    "values": [
      ["Date", "Qwer", "Wert", "Erty"],
      ["1.2.20", "1234", "2345", "3456"]
    ]
  }]
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]